# Distance output from Google Maps API - remove unit text

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API to get the distance on a round trip including two waypoints.  I want to use the distance output from this to calculate "trip cost" - (distance*price)/mpg.  However, since the distance output includes text, the formula rejects it.  Is there a way to remove the text (mi/km, etc.) from the distance output?

Answer (score 1):

The [Distance](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Distance) returned for each leg has two members:

> **text**  string  A string representation of the distance value, using the UnitSystem specified in the request.
>
> **value** number  The distance in meters.

If you don't want the units, use the value in meters and convert it to the distance unit you prefer.